# Hibernate | Identifier Generation Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm getting an exception when I try to save some data through hibernate persistence layer, the exception is

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): hbm.Employee


public void saveEmployee(Employee empValue) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee emp;
        if (empValue.getEmpcode() != null) {
            emp = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, empValue.getEmpcode());
            if (emp != null) {
                System.out.println("Test");
                emp.setEmpcode(empValue.getEmpcode());
                emp.setDepartment(createDepartment("DEEE"));
                emp.setEmpfname(empValue.getEmpfname());
                emp.setEmplname(empValue.getEmplname());
                emp.setEmpdob(empValue.getEmpdob());
                emp.setEmpstatus(empValue.getEmpstatus());
                emp.setEmptelno(empValue.getEmptelno());
                emp.setAuditfield(empValue.getAuditfield());
                session.update(emp);
            }
        } else 
        {
            emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmpcode(empValue.getEmpcode());
            emp.setDepartment(createDepartment("DEEE"));
            emp.setEmpfname(empValue.getEmpfname());
            emp.setEmplname(empValue.getEmplname());
            emp.setEmpdob(empValue.getEmpdob());
            emp.setEmpstatus(empValue.getEmpstatus());
            emp.setEmptelno(empValue.getEmptelno());
            emp.setAuditfield(empValue.getAuditfield());
            session.save(emp);
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
```

as you can see the class get assigned within appropriate places, I'm confused about the exception, expecting some help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()` is self explanatory.

This happens because you are using the `assigned` built-in generator. The `assigned` generator explicitly tells Hibernate that the application is going to assign the identifier. From the section [5.1.4.1. Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator):

> lets the application assign an identifier to the object before `save()` is called. This is the default strategy if no `<generator>` element is specified.

If this is not what you want, use another generator, for example `native` (this 
*selects `identity`, `sequence` or `hilo` depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database*):

```
<class name="LineItem" table="`Line Item`">
  <id name="id" column="`Item Id`"/>
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  ...
</class>
```

Comment: How to generate this configure with annotation?

Answer (score 5):

The Exception says that you have no value assigned to field marked with @id in the Employee class. How that this class look like? Are you trying to generate the Id values through one of the provided generators or would you like to set them manually?

Comment: it is set to class="assigned" in .hbm file

Comment: @MMRUser can you clarify which field is marked as the "id" in your mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Use following kind of code to save employee
if this is not helpful please paste mapping file to know details of field empCode.

```
helper = new HibernateHelper();
Customer custObject;
 if (customer.getId() == 0) {
                custObject = new Customer();
                custObject.setCreatetimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            } else {
                custObject = (Customer) helper.getSession().load(Customer.class, customer.getId());
            }
            custObject.setName(customer.getName());
            custObject.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
            custObject.setBillToAddress(customer.getBillToAddress());
            custObject.setBillToPerson(customer.getBillToPerson());
            custObject.setUpdatetimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            custObject.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
            custObject.setDeleted(false);
            Currency curr = (Currency) helper.getSession().load(Currency.class, x);
            custObject.setCurrencyId(curr);

            custId = (Long) helper.getSession().save(custObject);
            helper.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-boot JPA then you can simply add this annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

This issue comes, when persistence layer doesn't have an option in place to generate/create value for primary key of the Entity in question. There are more options for primary key generation.

You can have a look at java docs for [GenerationType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html)